# Errno 10109 getaddrinfo failed returns when params are entered within tkinter window

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, paramiko

```
def oratab(ip, username,password):
    # ip = '10.10.10.10'
    # username = 'root'
    # password = 'password'
    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    remote_conn_pre.connect(ip, username, password, look_for_keys=False,
                            allow_agent=False)
   ... the function returns the files listing on Linux machine

def reply(ip, username, password):
    showinfo(title='Reply', message=list(oratab(ip, password, username)))

top = Tk()
Label(top, text='enter IP: ').pack()
ent = Entry(top)
ent.pack()
Label(top, text='enter username: ').pack()
ent2 = Entry(top)
ent2.pack()
Label(top, text='enter password: ').pack()
ent3 = Entry(top)
ent3.pack()
btn = Button(top, text='Submit', command=(lambda: reply(ent.get(), ent2.get(), ent3.get())))
btn.pack()
top.mainloop()

> addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed
```

If I pass IP only (def oratab(IP) and def reply(IP)) and specify username and password on oratab function (simply removing comment sign in 2 lines) it will return the right results.

Is it something with my lambda which doesn't take the second and third param comes within tkinter window: http://prntscr.com/erg1hs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared the Server was not available.